# Change node.js install location to "Users/johndoe"? How to? Good idea?

Tags: node.js, npm, macos-catalina

I'm using MacOS Catalina(10.15.4 - latest) and I'm doing a fresh install of node.js and npm.

I have been having permission errors and so I want to install npm inside of `Users/johndoe/` as explained here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally 
(Manually Change npm's Default Directory).

I have no problems with installing npm inside of `Users/johndoe` but should I be changing the location of the node.js (the current LTS version, 12.16.3) installation from `usr/local` to `Users/johndoe` as well? How can I do this? Can I simply move the files from `usr/local` to a new folder in `Users/johndoe` or would that cause problems? Are there any security issues I should be aware of?

I have been struggling to find the answer to this because most information is out of date. I'm using zsh where most of the information I can find is using bash. I have also been hunting around for the answer through the node.js documentation and the npm documentation but I haven't had any success because this seems to be an issue that isn't specific to either, it's about their interaction.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i prefer (by far) local install, especially with the never ending growing list of osx-f'ups that break  a developer's stack. Look into installing nvm (locally) so you can have multiple versions of node and npm.  This plays well in WebStorm.

Comment: Thank you for answering. npm would be installed locally. How do you install node.js locally?

Comment: nvm (node version manager) installs one (or more) node.js in your account, its cohort of node modules at it may, and allows you to switch easily.  Look here : https://medium.com/@isaacjoe/best-way-to-install-and-use-nvm-on-mac-e3a3f6bc494d .

Comment: I have tried to install nvm using `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash` but it has been unsuccessful. As I am using zsh not bash, should I be changing the curl to `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | zsh`? I am also using a ".profile". In the terminal, `nvm` returns `zsh: command not found: nvm` after running the original curl.